# When is writing complex number in polar form better then rectangular form

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

Today I was wondering when it's better to use polar form to write complex numbers vs. rectangular form.

Let's suppose we have this complex number in rectangular form: $\sqrt{3}-i$

and we also have the same number in polar form: $2(\cos{(-\frac{\pi}{6}})+i\sin{(-\frac{\pi}{6}})),$

so both forms show this complex number, but when to use which form -- what are the advantages of polar form vs. rectangular one?

Thanks for answering and best regards.

Comment: (Don't forget to write the full number in polar form, else it may not be the same number...)

Comment: I think it’s generally easier to add in rectangular form and multiply in polar form

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. I’m voting to close this question because it's too vague. The only answer that makes sense (to me) is that as you learn more about working with complex numbers you will learn which contexts suggest which forms. One of the first things to learn is how to express $\sqrt{3} - 1$ in polar form. What you write in the question is wrong.

Comment: "*we also have the same number in polar form: $-\frac{\pi}{6}$*"  Surely, you mean $2e^{-i\pi/6}$ instead

Comment: Your question could be improved by adding some [additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) regarding what you do already know about these issues. Do you know some situations where rectangular form is appropriate? Others where polar form is appropriate? Are there some specific situations where you are not sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> wondering when it's better to use polar form to write complex numbers vs. rectangular form

In rectangular form, complex numbers are easy to add; just add their components.

In polar form, complex numbers are easy to multiply;

just multiply their magnitudes and add their arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I would also vote to close this since the original poster doesn't seem to understand what the "polar form" of a complex number is!  The polar form of $\sqrt{3}- i$ is NOT "$\frac{\pi}{6}$".  For one thing, $\frac{\pi}{6}$ is a real number with imaginary part 0.  Then absolute value of $\sqrt{3}- i$ is $\sqrt{(\sqrt{3})^2+ 1^2}= \sqrt{4}= 2$.  The argument is $arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{-1}\right)= arctan(-\sqrt{3})= -\frac{\pi}{6}$.

The polar form of $\sqrt{3}- i$ is $2\left(\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)+ i \sin\left(-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right)= 2\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)- i \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\right)$ or, in an abbreviated form, $2 cis\left(-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$ or sometimes just "\left(2, -\fra{\pi}{6}\right)$.

In any case, the product of (a+ bi)(c+ di) is (ac- bd)+ (ad+ bc)i while the product of (r cis(t))(u cis(v)) is ru(cis(t+ v).  The second is much easier.  That is especially true of powers.  $(a+ bi)^n$ is wicked, while $(r cis(u))^n= r^n cis(nu)$.