# Sum and subtraction of euler form numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I was unable to find it in nowhere.

How to do sum and subtraction of complex numbers in euler form?

I will give an problem as example:

z1 = 2·exp( -j15° ) and z2 = 13·exp( j45° )

What is z1 + z2 in euler form?

and what is z1 - z2 in euler form?

How i find the results of problems like this, that is, how i do sum and subtraction of complex numbers in Euler Form?

Comment: It's usually easier to add complex numbers in the form $x+yi$ with real $x$ and $y$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner So worth I transform it to the form x + yi to make the sum and subtraction? But not for multiplication and quotient?

Comment: Yes; see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203175/when-is-writing-complex-number-in-polar-form-better-then-rectangular-form)

Comment: Thank you :D ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add or subtract complex numbers in Euler form,

it's usually easiest to convert them to the form $x+yi$ with real $x$ and $y$

and then add or subtract them.